# android Frame Animation not working in BaseAdapter

Tags: android, animation, android-listview, frame, animationdrawable

I am downloading the images from server and storing in array in bitmap format,
Then i intialise the Frame Animation and want to animate it from array viz i made previously,

The problem i am facing is that frame animation is not animating..

```
final AnimationDrawable frame_anim=new AnimationDrawable();
frame_anim.addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),stadium_list.get(position)), 100);
frame_anim.addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),sponser_list.get(position)), 100);
stadium_image.setBackgroundDrawable(frame_anim);
frame_anim.setVisible(true, true);
frame_anim.setOneShot(false);
notifyDataSetChanged();

stadium_image.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        frame_anim.start();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Animation", 1000).show();
    }
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code showing you missed to get background  which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.

AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) YOURIMAGEVIEW.getBackground();

[AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)

Comment: i am not getting the resources from drawable folder,i have made an array of bitmap images,and because of final keyword i cant re-assign the animationdrawable variable